# jquery onchange not work after a first call ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

i try to pass from a frame to a div
after a first call ajax jquery on change not work
then in frame it's working

i load a first time my page when click on the menu.
i select a personnage 
the refresh is ok

but after when i try to modif XPS the event onchange not work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var URL_BASE='{$URL_BASE}'</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}page.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}menu_mj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frame-menu">
 <a href="#" onclick="return menu_displaycentre('frame-centre','{$URL_BASE}page.php');
  ma page
 </a>
</div>
<div id="frame-centre">
</div>
```

extract page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$URL_BASE}js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="recherche" name="recherche" action="">
   <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="rech_perso" />
   RECHERCHE D'UN COMPTE<br />
   Id,Login, email, ip ou nom de personnage : (2 lettres min)<br />
   <input type="text" name="query" size="30" />
   <input type="submit" value="RECHERCHER" onclick="PJ_Recherche()" />
</form>
 <input type="text" size="10" name="XPS" value="{$PJ.XPS}" id="XPS"/>
```

perso.js

```
    $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#XPS").change(function () {
//$('#XPS').live('onchange',function () {
  alert('titi');
   var champsid = ($(this).attr('id'))
   var champsvaleur = $('input[id=XPS]').val()
   var idpj = ($("#idpj").val());
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "updatebdd.php",
   data: 'id='+idpj+'&champ='+champsid+'&value='+ champsvaleur,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html) { // If is everything ok
   }
   });
   });
   });
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
function PJ_Recherche() {
   var url=URL_BASE+'persos.php';
   new Ajax.Updater(
      'frame-centre', 
        url,
        {
        method : 'post', 
        parameters: Form.serialize('recherche')
        }
    );
parent.document.getElementById('frame-centre').innerHTML ='Please Wait...';
return false;
}
```

...

i block on this from 3 days some have the answer?

Comment: You probably need event delegation, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 6):

you have to use [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/), as element is modified after DOM load:

```
$(document).on('click','#XPS',function () {

................
...............
.............

});
```

Comment: I have same issue where I have an ajax call that updates textbox.
I tried this but unable to fire the change event of that textbox.
`$("#txtInput").on("change", "#txtInput", function () { myfunction() });`
Any suggestions?

Comment: In first selector put $(document)